# How to wire headphones?

Tags: audio, repair, headphones

I'm currently trying to fix my headphones with a TRRS jack that I recently purchased. I'm using my multimeter and have figured out that green/blue wires together make up the left audio channel and red/black make up the right audio channel. How would I wire this? It seems that there are two grounds but I don't know which is which. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have only one ground. The last pin is used for MIC. Here's a picture where the pins are described.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why did you buy a Tip, Ring, Ring, Sleeve?  Almost all stereo jacks are Tip, Ring, Sleeve. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29) for more info.

To do this properly you would need to do a conductivity test of the old phone jack to the different colored wires.  If that is not possible it is likely you can twist 1 wire from each side together and connect that to the sleeve. Then connect the remaining 2 wires (independently) to tip and ring.  If by chance it works, you have a 50% chance the phase will be correct.  And a 50% chance the left channel is on the left and the right channel is on the right.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, but my headphones actually have a mic. In total there are 5 wires: red, geeen, blue, black, and a copper/red wire.

Comment: I will guess that blue and black is ground. Red and grenn are positive for left/right, and copper/red are positive for mic.